# Assign values to name in excel

Tags: excel

How can I assign a value to a name in excel that i could easily fill out same value to a name but in a different sheet. I know I could do in in python with openxlm lib but as it is my computer from work I can't install anything, even python. My database is very long and I have more than 10 sheets to fill out. Names doesn't appear in every sheets therefore i can't just copy and paste whole column with values
[image] .

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quite easy: I have created two sheets ("Sheet1" and "Sheet2"), I filled both sheets as you have shown, and in the "VALUE" column of "Sheet2" (`D2`, I mean), I have filled in following formula:

```
=VLookup(A2;Sheet1!$A$1:$D$6;4;FALSE)
```

Some explanation:

- `A2` stands for the first entry, which is searched (by this I mean "John", the first entry in the "Name" column in "Sheet2").
- `Sheet1!$A$1:$D$6` is the table, where I am searching in. It is crucial to use the dollar-signs, as, when you drag your formula down, the first reference will change (`A2` will be come `A3`, `A4`, ..., but `$A$1:$D$6` will not, you will always continue searching in the same table).
- `4` means that the fourth column of the searched table will be shown (the "VALUE" column in "Sheet1").
- `FALSE` means: do not use approximative search, but use exact one.

Now you can drag that formula down, until the end of your "Sheet2".